# Regex: Match all the words that contains some word

Tags: regex, words

I want to match all the words that contains the word "oana". I put "OANA" with uppercase letters in some words, at the beginning, middle, and at the end of words.

`blah OANAmama blah aOANAtata aOANAt msmsmsOANAasfasfa mOANAmsmf OANAtata OANA3 oanTy`

Anyway, I made a regex, but it is not very good, because it doesn't select all words that contains "oana"

`\b\w+(oana)\w+\b`

Can anyone give me another solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a case insensitive flag and replace `+` with `*`:

```
/\b\w*oana\w*\b/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TiP1Y2/1) (a global modifier may or may not be used, depending on the regex engine). The case insensitive modifier may be passed as an inline option in some regex engines - `(?i)\b\w*oana\w*\b`.

Here,

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `oana` - the required char string inside a word
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: just fine. Thank you very muck Wiktor !